# remove placeholder attribute on focus in plain JS (non-jQuery)

Tags: javascript, dom

**I would simply like to remove the attribute with my `if` condition and add it back with my `else`.**

```
function onFocusChange () { 
  if (document.getElementById("input").focus()) { 
     document.getElementById("input").placeholder = "";
   else { 
     document.getElementById("input").placeholder = "This is Placeholder Text";   
   }
  }
}
```

mark-up:

```
<label for="input">
  Question #1:
</label>
<input type="text" id="input" name="Address" required="required" placeholder="This is Placeholder Text" />
```

Comment: *"For demo purposes..."* your question does not show [any research effort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).

Comment: ... and  [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute).

Comment: Why remove it when browser does it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `focus` & `blur` event

```js
var element = document.getElementById('input');
element.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  element.setAttribute('placeholder', '')

})

element.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  element.setAttribute('placeholder', 'This is Placeholder Text')

})
```

```html
<label for="input">
  Question #1:
</label>
<input type="text" id="input" name="Address" required="required" placeholder="This is Placeholder Text" />
```

Answer (score 4):

To remove attribute you can use `element.removeAttribute("placeholder");`